# Flask app.add_url_rule in decorator error

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I have a bunch of decorators in my Flask routes that I am trying to condense into one (including `@app.route`).

I have the following `@route` function:

```
from functools import wraps
def route(route, method):
    def decorator(f):
        print 'decorator defined'
        print 'defining route'
        app.add_url_rule(route, methods=method, view_func=f)
        print 'route defined'
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print 'Hello'
            # do stuff here such as authenticate, authorise, check request json/arguments etc.
            # these will get passed along with the route and method arguments above.
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

and a sample route:

```
@route('/status', ['GET'])
def status():
    return Response('hi', content_type='text/plain')
```

The route is getting defined, but `wrapper()` never gets called, which is really odd. When I move `app.add_url_rule` outside of the decorator to the end of the file, then `wrapper()` gets called; so `decorator defined` statement prints on Flask startup, and `Hello` prints when I hit the `GET /status` route as expected.

However, when I put `app.add_url_rule` back into the decorator as shown above, `decorator defined` prints on startup but when I call `GET /status`, it does not print `Hello` as if `app.add_url_rule` overrides the `wrapper()` function that I defined somehow.

Why does this happen? It looks like `app.add_url_route` hijacks my function in some odd/unexpected way.

How can I get `wrapper()` to be called once the route is hit, while defining `app.add_url_rule` in the decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You registered the *original function*, not the wrapper, with Flask. Whenever the route matches, Flask calls `f`, not `wrapper`, because that's what you registered for the route.

Tell Flask to call `wrapper` when the route matches, instead:

```
def route(route, method):
    def decorator(f):
        print 'decorator defined'
        print 'defining route'
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print 'Hello'
            # do stuff here such as authenticate, authorise, check request json/arguments etc.
            # these will get passed along with the route and method arguments above.
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        app.add_url_rule(route, methods=method, view_func=wrapper)
        print 'route defined'
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: Nice! So for each route, will Python store a different wrapper which will then call the proper `f`?

Comment: @Nayefc: your decorator creates a different wrapper for each decorated `f`, so yes.